# AWS Load Balancer appends :80 to url on http to https 301 redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, https, amazon-elb

When I go to my example application: `https://example.com/r/123` it works as expected.

If I go to `http://example.com/r/123` it seems the load balancer changes the url to `https://example.com:80/r/123`.

This page results in a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Is it possible to make AWS not add the port(`:80`) in the redirect?

[image]

Comment: You have an HTTPS listener on port `80` apparently? It should be on port `443`. Please include your load balancer listener configuration in your qustion.

Comment: I added an image of the listeners. Is this enough?

Comment: I think your backend `nuxt` server may be the thing performing the redirect. There is nothing in your load balancer configuration that would cause it to do that.

Comment: I agree with @Mark B, probably your backend is the one doing this redirect. If you want to confirm this, instead of forward to `nuxt`, add a fixed response.

Comment: @Azize I changed the 443 to a fixed response. When going to `https://example.com/r/123`, I get the fixed response. When I go to `https://example.com:80/r/123` I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` as before. I do not fully understand if this confirms it or not.

Comment: It confirm, you can't do HTTPS request on port 80. When you request HTTPS on port 443, the one configured with SSL, it works fine and gives you the fixed response. When you use port 80 you must use HTTP, not HTTPS. In this case HTTP should be used just to redirect to HTTPS, nothing else.

Comment: If you backend need to do redirect, if need to use just HTTPS or HTTPS and port 443. But it can't mix HTTP with port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by changing the server IP to `0.0.0.0` instead of the default value of `localhost` in the nuxt server config.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
},
```